# Wordpressで複数の画像をアップロードする際にエラー

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3

AmazonS3とWordpressを連携させてWordpressにメディア画像をアップロードするとS3サーバに送られます。

50枚ほど複数アップロードすると、その中の2～5枚ほどがエラーになります。エラーになったjpgファイルは同じ容量サイズ（500kb)ほどあり、そのjpgURLを開くと

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>2F58C6F387973191</RequestId>
<HostId>
fPLgB1R4fmCFBgXnduqTiJSusxBU1y8GHQUB69wqYQqLTRIPK5n+1k0JUmkiY5gmg8w9lhx90U4=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

といったXMLエラーページが表示されます。
再び、同じ画像をアップロードすると成功します。

考えられるのはインターネット環境がよくないので、タイムアウト設定でしょうか？
しかし、通常のサーバアップロードにすると、正常にできます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

自己解決しました。

```
/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

で

```
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_children = 5
```

を

```
pm.max_spare_servers = 15
pm.max_children = 15
```

にしたら治りました。英語版StackOverflowに書いてありました。

There are many possible reasons why your PHP-FPM would reach the max_children. Most common ones are:

A lot of parallel requests from your clients
Slow execution of the PHP scripts
Very low setting of the max_children
Looking at the specs of your machine, assuming there is nothing else than PHP+Nginx running, I think you could set it much higher than 5. You say you have 8 Cores, usually Nginx needs much less CPU than PHP, so with 5 children you will probably never be able to use all of them. I'm usually setting it to something like the number of cores x 2 or number of cores x 4, depending on the memory consumption of your PHP scripts.